# Adding instances to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm have created a new ArrayList and I just need to add instances to it, however Java's saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'add' ". 
I have looked at this question: ([how to change from arrays to one array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912335/how-to-change-from-arrays-to-one-array-list)), but I'm still receiving the error

Code:

```
public class EventController {

     ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

Event e1 = new Event("Drake", "5th October 2019", "19:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
    Event e2 = new Event("Drake", "6th October 2019", "21:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
    Event e3 = new Event("Ed Sheeran", "21st October 2019", "19:00-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
    Event e4 = new Event("Ed Sheeran", "22nd October 2019", "20:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
    Event e5 = new Event("Jorja Smith", "3rd November 2019", "19:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
    Event e6 = new Event("Jorja Smith", "4rd November 2019", "20:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
    Event e7 = new Event("Coldplay", "15th December 2019", "17:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
    Event e8 = new Event("Coldplay", "16th December 2019", "19:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");

    events.add(e1);
}
```

Error:
[image: Error:]

Comment: can you please copy/paste the code here, the image is quite dim.

Comment: `events.add(e1);` can't be executed at class level, it should be executed in method, constructor, or initialization-block (which is moved later by compiler to constructors). Can someone find proper duplicate for this? I can lend my dupe-hammer if needed, just ping me.

Comment: If you want to add data when you declare `List` then you can use anonymous innerclass: `new ArrayList<Event>() {{ this.add(new Event("Drake", "5th October 2019", "19:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena")); }};`

Comment: Write a main() method and place your code into it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your code inside either the constructor or a function.

```
public class EventController {

    public EventController() {
       ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

       Event e1 = new Event("Drake", "5th October 2019", "19:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
       Event e2 = new Event("Drake", "6th October 2019", "21:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
       Event e3 = new Event("Ed Sheeran", "21st October 2019", "19:00-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
       Event e4 = new Event("Ed Sheeran", "22nd October 2019", "20:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
       Event e5 = new Event("Jorja Smith", "3rd November 2019", "19:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
       Event e6 = new Event("Jorja Smith", "4rd November 2019", "20:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
       Event e7 = new Event("Coldplay", "15th December 2019", "17:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");
       Event e8 = new Event("Coldplay", "16th December 2019", "19:30-late", "Leeds", "First Direct Arena");

       events.add(e1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend a class to Activity or you can write code in a method to execute add for ArrayList().